# Orfeo Toolbox segmentation - increasing n segments

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation, object

I'm checking out the parameters for Orfeo's *Segmentation* tool and I'd like to know how to increase the number of segments that are output in the vector output.

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_Segmentation.html

For example, I'm testing a 50 cm resolution RGB image of open fields separated by hedge rows and forest. With all of the default parameters, it seems to make very large, contiguous polygons over the fields even though within the fields there's a variety of different textures and colours. I want these details to be picked up.

More specific Q's:

- what does "spatial radius" control/do?
- range radius?
- mode convergence?

Comment: Maybe this lab explanation will help:  http://faculty.wwu.edu/wallin/envr442/ENVI/442_segmentation_ENVI__Orfeo_acme5_9_2021.htm

Comment: Thanks. I managed to advance this on my own, but this looks useful.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that increasing the max amount of iterations, decreasing the mode convergence threshold, and decreasing the minimum region size will increase both the amount of polygons you end up with, and the sensitivity to fine textural details in your image.